# Complex class polymorphism and lazy-loaded components

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, ecmascript-6

I'm having an issue defining a base class and child classes, which handle initialization differently. I want it to work in ES6 but allow babel to transpile to ES5, and currently babel does not have a backwards compatible translation for `new.target` so I'm looking for something "close enough".

```
class Complex {
  constructor(real, imag, abs, arg) {
    if (new.target === Complex) {
      real = arguments.length > 0 && real !== undefined ? real : 0;
      imag = arguments.length > 1 && imag !== undefined ? imag : 0;
      abs  = arguments.length > 2 && abs  !== undefined ? abs  : Math.sqrt(real * real + imag * imag);
      arg  = arguments.length > 3 && arg  !== undefined ? arg  : Math.atan2(imag, real);

      this.real = real;
      this.imag = imag;
      this.abs  = abs >= 0 ? abs : -abs;
      // limits arg between (-pi, pi] and also corrects phase for negative abs
      this.arg  = arg ? -((-arg + (abs >= 0 ? Math.PI : 0)) % (Math.PI * 2) - Math.PI) : abs < 0 ? Math.PI : 0;
    }
  }

  // ... all mathematical static and non-static methods will go here
}

Complex.Cartesian = class Cartesian extends Complex {
  constructor(real = 0, imag = 0, abs, arg) {
    super();

    this.real = real;
    this.imag = imag;

    if (arguments.length === 4) {
      Object.defineProperties(this, {
        abs: {
          configurable: true,
          enumerable: true,
          value: abs >= 0 ? abs : -abs,
          writable: true,
        },
        arg: {
          configurable: true,
          enumerable: true,
          value: arg ? -((-arg + (abs >= 0 ? Math.PI : 0)) % (Math.PI * 2) - Math.PI) : abs < 0 ? Math.PI : 0,
          writable: true,
        },
      });
    }
  }

  get abs() {
    const value = Math.sqrt(this.real * this.real + this.imag * this.imag);

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'abs', {value, configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true});

    return value;
  }

  get arg() {
    const arg = Math.atan2(this.imag, this.real);
    const value = arg ? -((-arg + Math.PI) % (Math.PI * 2) - Math.PI) : 0;

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'arg', {value, configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true});

    return value;
  }
};

Complex.Polar = class Polar extends Complex {
  constructor(abs = 0, arg = 0, real, imag) {
    super();

    this.abs = abs >= 0 ? abs : -abs;
    this.arg = arg ? -((-arg + (abs >= 0 ? Math.PI : 0)) % (Math.PI * 2) - Math.PI) : abs < 0 ? Math.PI : 0;

    if (arguments.length === 4) {
      Object.defineProperties(this, {
        real: {
          configurable: true,
          enumerable: true,
          value: real,
          writable: true,
        },
        imag: {
          configurable: true,
          enumerable: true,
          value: imag,
          writable: true,
        },
      });
    }
  }

  get real() {
    const value = this.abs * Math.cos(this.arg);

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'real', {value, configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true});

    return value;
  }

  get imag() {
    const value = this.abs * Math.sin(this.arg);

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'imag', {value, configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true});

    return value;
  }
};
```

The general idea is to have a base class `Complex()` that handles initialization of all complex components (`real`, `imag`, `abs`, `arg`) when invoked directly, but not when invoked by child classes `Cartesian()` or `Polar()`, which use lazy-loaded `abs` and `arg`, or `real` and `imag` respectively.

My idea is to use `this instanceof Object && this.constructor === Complex` instead of `new.target`, but I'm not sure if that handles all edge cases exactly the same.

Any other advice not directly related to my specific issue is also welcome.

<sub>The code above is under MIT license, so if you plan on "borrowing" it for anything, please provide credit accordingly.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up side-stepping the issue entirely by extending the `Complex` class with ES5 `prototype` chaining instead of ES6 `extends`:

```
class Complex {
  constructor(real = 0, imag = 0, abs = Math.sqrt(real * real + imag * imag), arg = Math.atan2(imag, real)) {
    this.real = real;
    this.imag = imag;
    this.abs  = abs >= 0 ? abs : -abs;
    this.arg  = arg ? -((-arg + (abs >= 0 ? Math.PI : 0)) % (Math.PI * 2) - Math.PI) : abs < 0 ? Math.PI : 0;
  }

  // ...
};

const Cartesian = Complex.Cartesian = function Cartesian(real = 0, imag = 0) {
  this.real = real;
  this.imag = imag;
};

Cartesian.prototype = Object.create(Complex.prototype, {
  constructor: {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    value: Cartesian,
    writable: true,
  },
  abs: {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    get() {
      const value = Math.sqrt(this.real * this.real + this.imag * this.imag);

      Object.defineProperty(this, 'abs', {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        value,
        writable: true
      });

      return value;
    },
    set(value) {
      Object.defineProperty(this, 'abs', {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        value,
        writable: true,
      });

      return value;
    },
  },
  arg: {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    get() {
      const arg = Math.atan2(this.imag, this.real);
      const value = arg ? -((-arg + Math.PI) % (Math.PI * 2) - Math.PI) : 0;

      Object.defineProperty(this, 'arg', {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        value,
        writable: true,
      });

      return value;
    },
    set(value) {
      Object.defineProperty(this, 'arg', {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        value,
        writable: true,
      });

      return value;
    },
  },
});

const Polar = Complex.Polar = function Polar(abs = 0, arg = 0) {
  this.abs = abs >= 0 ? abs : -abs;
  this.arg = arg ? -((-arg + (abs >= 0 ? Math.PI : 0)) % (Math.PI * 2) - Math.PI) : abs < 0 ? Math.PI : 0;
};

Polar.prototype = Object.create(Complex.prototype, {
  constructor: {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    value: Polar,
    writable: true,
  },
  real: {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    get() {
      const value = this.abs * Math.cos(this.arg);

      Object.defineProperty(this, 'real', {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        value,
        writable: true,
      });

      return value;
    },
    set(value) {
      Object.defineProperty(this, 'real', {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        value,
        writable: true,
      });

      return value;
    },
  },
  imag: {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    get() {
      const value = this.abs * Math.sin(this.arg);

      Object.defineProperty(this, 'imag', {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        value,
        writable: true,
      });

      return value;
    },
    set(value) {
      Object.defineProperty(this, 'imag', {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        value,
        writable: true,
      });

      return value;
    },
  },
});
```

This allowed me to write the constructors without requiring the call to `super()`, which was what created the issue in the first place.